# Go through certain sets of html tags

Tags: php, curl

I need a little help here please.What am trying to do is pull all the content in b nodes.

```
<P><B>Credit Weighting: </B>5<BR><BR>
<B>Teaching Period(s): </B>Teaching Periods 1 and 2.<BR><BR>
<B>No. of Students: </B>-.<BR><BR>
<B>Pre-requisite(s): </B>None<BR><BR>
<P><A HREF="#top" class="toppage">[Top of page]</A></P>

<P><B>Credit Weighting: </B>20<BR><BR>
<B>Teaching Period(s): </B>Teaching Periods 1 and 2.<BR><BR>
<B>No. of Students: </B>-.<BR><BR>
<B>Pre-requisite(s): </B>None<BR><BR>
<P><A HREF="#top" class="toppage">[Top of page]</A></P>

<P><B>Credit Weighting: </B>10<BR><BR>
<B>Teaching Period(s): </B>Teaching Periods 1 and 2.<BR><BR>
<B>No. of Students: </B>-.<BR><BR>
<B>Pre-requisite(s): </B>None<BR><BR>
<P><A HREF="#top" class="toppage">[Top of page]</A></P>
```

I was able to pull data from the first set.Below is my sample code that does this

```
    // GETTING ALL THE B NODE STUFFS AND PRINTING IT'S CONTENTS
    $result = array();
    foreach($document->getElementsByTagName('b') as $node){
    $result[preg_replace('/:\s+$/','',$node->textContent)] = trim($node->nextSibling->textContent);
    } 
    var_dump($result);
    echo '<br /><br />';
```

Now what am trying to do is loop through the three set of html code to get all the b nodes and get the contetnts.How could I go about this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
$result = array();
$id= -1;
foreach($document->getElementsByTagName('b') as $node){
    $field= preg_replace('/:\s+$/','',$node->textContent);
    if ( $field == "Credit Weighting" ) $id++;
    $result[$id][$field]= trim($node->nextSibling->textContent);
}.
var_dump($result);
```

This gets you:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(4) {
    'Credit Weighting' =>
    string(1) "5"
    'Teaching Period(s)' =>
    string(25) "Teaching Periods 1 and 2."
    'No. of Students' =>
    string(2) "-."
    'Pre-requisite(s)' =>
    string(4) "None"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(4) {
    'Credit Weighting' =>
    string(2) "20"
    'Teaching Period(s)' =>
    string(25) "Teaching Periods 1 and 2."
    'No. of Students' =>
    string(2) "-."
    'Pre-requisite(s)' =>
    string(4) "None"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(4) {
    'Credit Weighting' =>
    string(2) "10"
    'Teaching Period(s)' =>
    string(25) "Teaching Periods 1 and 2."
    'No. of Students' =>
    string(2) "-."
    'Pre-requisite(s)' =>
    string(4) "None"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, thats what the code does, right? Or do you mean a flat array?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
preg_match_all("/\<B\>(.*)\<\/B>([^\<]+)/", $text, $regs);
```

assuming the second bit of data doesnt have html tags in it.

Comment: Sorry where exactly would I fit this regular expression in the code above ? All the above contents are within the body of html file.